# Exporting DataGridview To CSV every milliseconds

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, datagridview, datagrid

I have a function which Export my Windows.Form Application DataGridView to CSV.
It works fine, but the problem is that my DataGridView has 2 rows that updates every milliseconds, but the Output to CSV does not, It just output the value after Application close...

```
    public void writeCSV(DataGridView gridIn, string outputFile)
    {
        //test to see if the DataGridView has any rows
        if (gridIn.RowCount > 0)
        {
            string value = "";
            DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
            StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter(outputFile);

            //write header rows to csv
            for (int i = 0; i <= gridIn.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    swOut.Write(",");
                }
                swOut.Write(gridIn.Columns[i].HeaderText);
            }

            swOut.WriteLine();

            //write DataGridView rows to csv
            for (int j = 0; j <= gridIn.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                if (j > 0)
                {
                    swOut.WriteLine();
                }

                dr = gridIn.Rows[j];

                for (int i = 0; i <= gridIn.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                    {
                        swOut.Write(",");
                    }

                    value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                    //replace comma's with spaces
                    value = value.Replace(',', ' ');
                    //replace embedded newlines with spaces
                    value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");

                    swOut.Write(value);
                }
            }
            swOut.Close();
        }
    }
```

I called the function from the SetDataGridView() function which i use to update the DataGrids Row every seconds, but it still does not update every milliseconds as the DataGrid does.

How do i make this Update the CSV file every millisecond as the DataGridView.Rows itself updates?

Comment: Why would you update a data grid view every millisecond in the first place? You don't have a screen with an update frequency of 1000 Hz, so you will only be able to see a fraction of the updates.

Comment: I mean I update The row values every milliseconds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by calling the  `writeCSV(DataGridView,outputFile)` from `private void timer_0_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)` which are created automatically whenever a Timer Class has been added to a C# Application...
And, it started updating the CSV everytime the Tick Updates the DataGridView

Answer (score 0):

Add a **TargetUpdated** event to DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid TargetUpdated="DataGrid_TargetUpdated" ...
```

Then in each DataGrid column definitions set **NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True**:

```
<DataGridColumn Binding="{Binding Path=...,  NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,
 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Then in TargetUpdated handler call writeCSV method:

```
private void DataGrid_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
      writeCSV(DataGridView,outputFile)
}
```

Comment: Though, the Column itself does not change. But, the rows does....
Will this also work for rows or only column changes?

Comment: @ThisDude Each column change is as a result of row change.

Comment: Ok, thanks...
But, i think something is missing either in this code or Solution you provided...
I don't have any DataGrid definition. All Definitions i have are DataGridView.

Comment: These are the definitions, DataGridView(), DataGridViewTextBoxColumn(). The last one is the one with the Changing values.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from 
gridIn.Columns
To 
gridIn.HeaderRow.Cells
As gridIn.Columns does not provide data

Final code after replacing is :

```
 public void writeCSV(DataGridView gridIn, string outputFile)
{
    //test to see if the DataGridView has any rows
    if (gridIn.RowCount > 0)
    {
        string value = "";
        DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
        StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter(outputFile);

        //write header rows to csv
        for (int i = 0; i <= gridIn.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                swOut.Write(",");
            }
            swOut.Write(gridIn.HeaderRow.Cells[i].HeaderText);
        }

        swOut.WriteLine();

        //write DataGridView rows to csv
        for (int j = 0; j <= gridIn.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            if (j > 0)
            {
                swOut.WriteLine();
            }

            dr = gridIn.Rows[j];

            for (int i = 0; i <= gridIn.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    swOut.Write(",");
                }

                value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                //replace comma's with spaces
                value = value.Replace(',', ' ');
                //replace embedded newlines with spaces
                value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");

                swOut.Write(value);
            }
        }
        swOut.Close();
    }
}
```